# In Rails console, how do I show all sql selected attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This has been a confusing issue for me for years, and I've never asked about it. Why is it that I can't see `name` in the following console output even though I clearly selected it?

[image]

If I assign that output to a variable and say `relation.first.name` I will see the name, but I can't get the name to show in console. Also, if I convert the ActiveRecord relation to an array, I see a similar problem:

```
2.3.5 :070 > a.first
#<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging:0x00007ff9f3779aa8> {
    :id => 139
}
2.3.5 :071 > a.first.name
"phones"
```

Is there a better way to deal with this? For the moment, all I can figure is to map this to make it visible, which make writing queries a pain:

`a.map{|tag| [tag.id, tag.name]}`

Answer (score 3):

> `a.first.attributes`

You can also use `.attributes['column_name']` to extract the desired information without relying on dot syntax, which can provide unexpected results.

Comment: I guess what I was hoping for was a way to automagically map the result to a readable array without having to inspect the relations elements individually.

Comment: If you're looking to make it readable in STDOUT, I would personally just do something along the lines of `puts JSON.pretty_generate a.first.attributes.to_h`

Comment: When you say a.first, that is just looking at one element of the relation again.

Comment: Sorry, Misunderstanding on my part; you're looking at being able to apply the view-ability to all elements of the returned enumerable, yes?  In which case you're going to have to Map or Each at some point, but at the very least you can use #.attributes to give you a named reusable function for future use cases.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging` to do your query, the console is only showing attributes it knows about on `ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging`. I'm guessing that model doesn't have a `name` attribute, so it doesn't know to show it.

I believe the results of the query are also a bit confusing. The query shows `ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging` but I think it's showing the id for the tag.

Since you're trying to query for tags, I would maybe switch your query around if it's an option. I'm a little unclear on what you're trying to achieve, so I'm making an assumption. For example, here's what I would try:

```
Tag.joins(:taggings).where(:"taggings.context" => "topics")
```

By doing the join this way, you'll still have access to all of the taggings you're looking for; however, you'll get all of the tag attributes displayed as you want.

Comment: Thanks this is helpful, but I guess I was talking about a general issue that is more related to the way select works with active record relations.

Answer (score 0):

use `.pluck()` instead of `.select()`. Then you don't have intermediate objects who don't know about the `name` column.